# JAVA. Spring MVC, как создать view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Доброго времени суток. Впервые щупаю Spring MVC.
Есть простенький контроллер, с таким вот методом:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pets")

public class PetController {

@Autowired
private PetService petService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Pet> getAllPets() {
    return petService.getAllPets();
}
```

}

При запуске приложения в браузере выводится данные из toString() метода, который был описал в модельке Pet.java:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pet{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", age='" + age + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Каким образом я могу вывести это в табличке, в jsp странице?
П.С. Так как приложение простое, вместо БД был использован обычный List.

Comment: Тут 2 варианта: 1 - возвращать json и формировать таблицу с помощью js. 2 - запаковать результаты в тег <table><tr><td></td></tr></table> и возвращать как строку

Comment: Подключён ли какой-либо шаблонизатор к проекту?

Answer (score -1):

нужно прописать InternalResourceViewResolver бин для jsp, или ThymeleafViewResolver для html. 
Пример бина для InternalResourceViewResolver.
XML config:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
              <property name="prefix">
                  <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
               </property>
              <property name="suffix">
                 <value>.jsp</value>
              </property>
        </bean>
```

java config:

```
@Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver()
    {
        UrlBasedViewResolver res = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        res.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        res.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        res.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ.